# This is not a function while using in click event listener

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript file and have code like following

```
class test(){
    constructor(){
    }
    showBox(){
        var countBlock = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(countBlock); 
        countBlock.addEventListener('click', function(){
            this.showList()
        });
    }
    showList(){
        console.log('Element clicked')
    }
}
```

Code is working fine unless I click on element, when I click it shows `this.showList() is not a function`

Not sure how to resolve it

Comment: In the context of the event listener `this` is the element you clicked on.

Comment: You are not understanding `this` in JS. it is not like java. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
countBlock.addEventListener('click', () => this.showList());
```

Arrow functions lexically bind their context so `this` refers to the original context, which is the context of the code that contains the arrow function.

Or use a regular function but bind the enclosing `this` to your function:

```
countBlock.addEventListener('click', function () { this.showList() }.bind(this));
// or shorter, no need to wrap it in a function:
countBlock.addEventListener('click', this.showList.bind(this));
```

You can read more about `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Here is an example based on your code:

```js
class Test {
  showBox() {
    const countBlock = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(countBlock); 
    countBlock.addEventListener('click', () => this.showList());
  }
  showList() {
    console.log('Element clicked')
  }
}

new Test().showBox();
```

```css
p {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , That was a Quick and a perfect solution. Can you recommend me some articles or tutorials for javascript, I worked in jQuery and have only basic knowledge in javaScript

Comment: @Vikram Singh, you are welcome, a great reference for JavaScript would be [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), I find it very useful, otherwise, the documentation on MDN is great too.

Answer (score 1):

`class test(){` seems to be wrong, secondly use arrow function to bind `this`

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {}
  showBox() {
    console.log('Show Box Executed')
    var countBlock = document.createElement("div");
    let txt = document.createTextNode('Div');
    countBlock.appendChild(txt);
    document.body.appendChild(countBlock);
    countBlock.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.showList()
    });
  }
  showList() {
    console.log('Element clicked')
  }
}
let _t = new Test();
_t.showBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

**this.showList** is outside of the test class's scope because you wrapped it inside an anonymous function.
Do it like this:

```
class test{
    constructor(){
    }
    showBox(){
        var countBlock = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(countBlock); 
        countBlock.addEventListener('click', this.showList);
    }
    showList(){
        console.log('Element clicked')
    }
}
```